# MVC - For Loop - Add addition variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

im working on a project in mvc4 visual studio and have add an Uploadhandler.ashx.cs to upload the files.

the code is working to upload the files and insert into the information into my database.

Now what i try/need:

i have add a column where i want insert a number of each row like 1, 2 ,3, 4 etc...

in my code i have a for loop to do what i want for each file.

How can i generate a variable which add automatically +1 to insert it into my database.

i have try a lot of things like:

```
var a=1;

for(.......)
{

/*******My code****************/

a=a+1;
}
```

Hope that someone can give a hand with this:

here is my code:

```
 private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var a= 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    var file = context.Request.Files[i];

                    var fullpath = "/Files/"  + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                    var myfilename=Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                    file.SaveAs(fullpath);

                    statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(fullName, file.ContentLength, fullpath 

                    string sql1 = "insert into Image(FileName, Number) values (@FileName, @Number)";

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, cn))
                    {  
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", myfilename);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", a);
                        cn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cn.Close();
                    }

                    a = a + 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the number important on the client side? why not set the primary key to be the number and set it as an identity column ?

Comment: Your code should works, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Can the MVC tag be removed?

Comment: I do not know if you posted your entire code but I see a couple of errors: 1) Your SQL insert statement is missing a comma in the values part. 2) The parameters you are adding do not match the parameters in your SQL statement. 3) You are missing a call to SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery, so your SQL is never executed.

Comment: @PaulZahra and Alessandro  i don´t want it as a primary key.. the idea is to display the image in a different like i want

Comment: @JakobChristensen....Oops...  Srry.. it was my mistake... sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the variable as an `int`, and you can use `a++` to increment a by 1:

```
int a=1;

for(.......)
{

    /*******My code****************/

    a++;
}
```

Also, you have declared an integer `i` in your for loop that increments by 1 each time the loop is run, so you could use this instead of declaring a:

```
for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
     ...
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", i);
     ...
}
```

Finally, I'm not sure why you need this column in your database at all. If you are using it as a unique identifier the make it the Primary Key. You can then set this to auto-increment without needing to add the value each time.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use your iteration variable, `i`?

Comment: i try to use it, but the problem is that value of variable inserted in my database are always the same and not incremented

Comment: Then why don't you mark the column as `IDENTITY` so it'll auto-increment?

Answer (score 0):

Your pasted code has some errors, here is fixed code. (corrections are marked with ).

```
private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        var a= 1;

        **cn.Open();**

        for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = context.Request.Files[i];

            var fullpath = "/Files/"  + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)

            file.SaveAs(fullpath);

            **statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(fullName, file.ContentLength, fullpath));** 

            **string sql1 = "insert into Imagem(FileName, Number, Id_Magazine, Tem_Conteudo) values (@FileName, @Number, @Id_Magazine, @Tem_Conteudo)";**

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomeFicheiro", myfilename);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Magazine", context.Request.Form["MagazineId"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tem_Conteudo", false);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", a++);

                **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**
            }           
        }

        **cn.Close();**
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Regards,

Uroš